# Fraction step in inductive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In [https://sites.ualberta.ca/~smartynk/Resources/CMPUT%20272/inductionprobs.pdf](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Esmartynk/Resources/CMPUT%20272/inductionprobs.pdf) the following identity is stated, without a justification being given:

$${1 \over \sqrt{3k + 1}}* \frac{2k + 1}{2k + 2} = {1 \over \sqrt{3k + 1}}* \frac{1}{1 + {1 \over 2k + 1}}$$

I presume that

$$\frac{2k + 1}{2k + 2} = \frac{1}{1 + {1 \over 2k + 1}}$$

But I do not understand why this equality holds and no justification is given in the website above. Can anyone explain how the left-hand side of this equation is simplified to the right-hand side?

Comment: Have you tried to bring the RHS into a simple fraction Form? I think the identity is very obvious that way

Comment: @Manatee Pink What do you mean by bringing the RHS into simple fraction form?

Comment: @Peter Szilas: how do you get 11?

Comment: @Edward. Misprint: Numerator (2k+1); Denominator: 1+(2k+1); Now divide numerator and denominator bei (2k+1); New numerator =1; new denominator = 1/(2k+1)+1; Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Peter Szilas What is the principle that allows you to make the move "Now divide numerator and denominator by (2k + 1)"? Is it something like, "if you have a fraction a/b then for any z: a/b = (a/z) / (b/z)?"

Comment: 4/8=2/4; divide numerator and denominator by 2; 3/15=1/5, divide numerator and denominator by 5; the value of the fraction is not changed; Same here: divide num. (2k+1) by (2k+1) gives 1;  do the same with denominator 1+(2k+1) to get (1/(2k+1))+1; the value of the fraction is not changed.

Comment: @Peter Szilas Thanks! I missed out on high-school unfortunately and that helped me.

Comment: Edward; This is very basic. Perhaps read up a bit on fractions.

Comment: @Peter Szilas Yeah I don't know basic maths. But this site doesn't exclude per se questions on basic maths...Unfortunately, I don't know where to learn it, so I have to ask these questions here.

Comment: @Edward. Some web sites probably are suitable. I would try just googling. You may find online classes on introductory college algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, you should really learn elementary algebra before you start with that pdf you linked. It clearly requires it.

So, here is how you get from the RHS to the LHS. First of all if you have an integer $a$ and a fraction $\frac{p} {q} $ with integers $p$ and $q$, their sum equals $$\frac{aq+p} {q} $$ You multiply $a$ with the number below and add the product to the top. In your case $$1+\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{2k+2}{2k+1}$$

Second of all, if you have a double or nested fraction $$\frac{1}{\dfrac{p}{q}}$$ that is the same as $$\frac{q} {p} $$ which is just a single fraction. So in your case $$\frac{1}{\dfrac{2k+2}{2k+1}}=\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}$$